# Cygwin path: picking up Free Pascal make and not GNU make

Tags: cygwin

If I do "which make"

I get /usr/bin/make:

```
$ which make
/usr/bin/make
```

but if I then type "make"

I get a gcc error which shows a reference to the make that comes with Free Pascal:

```
$ make
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -g -c Array.c
gcc: installation problem, cannot exec `cpp': Permission denied
C:\Compilers\FPC\2.6.0\bin\i386-Win32\make.exe: *** [Array.o] Error 1
```

If I type "/usr/bin/make" instead of "make" I do NOT get the above error. I don't understand why the Free Pascal make is apparently getting executed when "which" shows the gnu make as the one to use, and for that matter, why the Free Pascal make gives an error that the GNU make does not.

Also, typing "which gcc" shows the expected GNU gcc:

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

"which cpp":

```
$ which cpp
/usr/bin/cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your PATH variable either from

- Control Panel -> System -> Advanced -> Edit Environment Variables

or from cygwin

- (assuming you use bash) export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH

For the latter case you can also edit your .bashrc and have it loaded every time you launch cygwin

Comment: My path (before making any changes) starts /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin .  /usr/local/bin is empty.